# How do I pass a spinbox value?

Tags: python-3.x

After getting the spinbox value, I am trying to pass it to a *for in range* loop.  The loop complains that value must be a string or a byte or number. When I manually put any number into the *range(0, 5) loop code* it works.  I want to replace
the *5* with the spinbox value..... can this be done?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please read up on
[how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and provide a
[minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to cast the value you get from `.get()` to an integer with `int()`.

Try this:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.sb = Spinbox(frame, from_=0, to=10)
        self.sb.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="Go", command=self.run)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)

    def run(self):
        for i in range(int(self.sb.get())):
            print(i)

root = Tk()

app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
```